# How do I isolate untrusted native code in Java?

Tags: java, multiprocessing, native, fault-tolerance

I have a piece of C library that I don't trust (in the sense that it might crash frequently). I am calling this from a Java process.

To prevent the crash in C library bringing the whole Java app. down, I figured it will be best if I spawn a dedicated java processes for this library, and let it interface with the Java app. through socket programming or RMI. Then, if a crash happens, I can just spawn another one and continue processing.

Is `ProcessBuilder` the way to go? Or are there any other easier ways?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, hosting the native code in a separate Java process is the only way to protect your application from native code.

As for easier ways, just minor implementation differences.  For example, not spawning the code from your Java application and wrapping the native code in a native wrapper that is configured to auto-start.  This would simplify the solution, if you have knowledge of C and sockets.  In this approach, RMI wouldn't be the best choice.

Even if you wrap the native code in Java, I still wouldn't pick RMI.  I have run into networking problems with Windows on WANs.  I would keep the communication simple if possible.  If the data is too complicated, maybe a basic serialization library. There are a few choices if you go down the XML route.  It's overkill, but you could also embed an http server and web services layer.  I don't know your system requirements, bu

Recovery is going to create a variety of challenges.  If it stops responding, do you just spawn another process...how many times are you willing to do that...  Process management from Java, leaves a lot to be desired.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of an easier way.

For the interaction between the parent and the child, i wouldn't use RMI or sockets - i'd use the child's standard input and output streams, accessible through the Process object. This is simple, efficient, and private. You can use the streams exactly as you would socket streams, although without any considerations of identity, addresses, authentication, and so on. You can write a protocol yourself, or use something like Thrift or Protocol Buffers to build a protocol from entity definitions.

Answer (score 0):

If performance isn't an issue and if there is a possibility of other applications hitting your "native" service, I'd go the RESTful or some other sort of web service oriented way. As far as re-spawning on crashes are concerned, as others have mentioned, just spawn the process as a service and you should be good to go.

If your application is the only entity which would be hitting this native service, then I'd prefer to go the RMI way as opposed to the pure socket way. IMO, RMI is a natural fit for inter-process communication (where the processes are Java processes). RMI has the concept of an "activatable" remote object which would be a natural fit given your requirements (auto-spawn on crash). Also, if using RMI, your application would speak with the native process through well defined Java interfaces rather than ad-hoc protocol contracts (which can be achieved using other high level solutions like web services but a real pain when it comes to raw sockets).

BTW, JFTR, we are using this strategy with our production app and it is working out quite well, YMMV. :-)